# Select distinct with joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select that return 10 same rows, i.e:

```
select distinct name from usernames where lastname='Ben';
```

I care only from the distinct values so I add distinct. Now I what to join this query with another query and still get the distinct values, so I did something like this:

```
select frd.value,
        frd.date,
        frd.loc_id,
        frd.loc_type
        (CASE distinct usr.name
            WHEN 'Alen' THEN 'Nice name'
            ELSE 'N/A' 
          END ) name
from usernames usr,
     friends    frd
where usr.lastname='Ben'
  and frd.id <20
  and frd.street<=10
  and frd.type='GOOD'
  and frd.loc_id=usr.loc_id;
```

My question is regarding the :

```
(CASE distinct usr.name
    WHEN 'Alen' THEN 'Nice name'
    ELSE 'N/A' 
 END ) name
```

Can I optimize this part?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    select frd.value,
            frd.date,
            frd.loc_id,
            frd.loc_type,
             usr.name
from friends as frd inner join (SELECT distinct (CASE usr.name
    WHEN 'Alen' THEN 'Nice name'
    ELSE 'N/A' 
 END, loc_ID from user) usr
ON frd.loc_ID = usr.loc_ID
    where usr.lastname='Ben'
      and frd.id <20
      and frd.street<=10
      and frd.type='GOOD'
```

Sorry I messed with join syntax so it was easier to read.